# Using Spring Cloud Stream with Rabbitmq, with exchange type "headers"

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have a project configured this way:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            rabbit:
                bindings:
                    myChannel:
                        consumer:
                            prefetch: 3
                            maxPriority: 10
                            exchangeType: headers
            bindings:
                myChannel:
                    destination: MyChannel
                    group: my-channel-readers
                    consumer:
                        concurrency: 4
                        max-attempts: 3
            binders:
                rabbit:
                    type: rabbit
```

this indeed creates the correct Exchange (as headers) and Queue, but it doesn't bind them.

Before I added the `exchangeType: headers` it created the exchange as `topic` and also bound the queue correctly.
Also, If I switch it to `exchangeType: topic` it creates the binding correctly.

I want this to be bound, and to send items only if they have/not have a certain header - how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto binding to a `headers` exchange is not currently supported; see [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).

> **exchangeType**
>
> The exchange type: `direct`, `fanout` or `topic` for non-partitioned destinations and direct or topic for partitioned destinations.
>
> Default: topic.

Of course, you can bind it manually.

It should be possible to autobind to this type of exchange. Feel free to open a new feature issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues).

Comment: I actually saw that in the doc, but it seemed very weird as in `org.springframework.amqp.core.ExchangeTypes` it is an option

Comment: Header exchanges **are** supported in the core spring-amqp framework; but for spring-cloud-stream, we need additional support to set binding arguments to configure a header exchange binding and there is currently no support for that. Hence my suggestion to request a new feature.

Comment: okay, thank you, I created this ticket: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/253

Comment: @GaryRussell, I see the feature was committed on Jul 2: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/254. So, it should be presented in latest SCStR release I believe.

Comment: It's a 3.0 feature. 3.0 will be released soon, the second release candidate (3.0.0.RC2) is available in the spring [milestone repo](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/). https://repo.spring.io/milestone/